# what does count(*) do exactly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I use oracle 11g.  I want maximum and minimum salary, and count of employees for each department, so I do this :

```
 select d.department_id, d.department_name, max(salary), min(salary), count(*) 
 from employees e ,
      departments d 
where e.department_id = d.department_id 
group by d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

and it works :

```
DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MAX(SALARY) MIN(SALARY)   COUNT(*)
------------- ------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------
          100 Finance                              12008        6900          6
           50 Shipping                              8200        2100         45
           70 Public Relations                     10000       10000          1
           30 Purchasing                           11000        2500          6
           90 Executive                            24000       17000          3
           10 Administration                        4400        4400          1
          110 Accounting                           12008        8300          2
           40 Human Resources                       6500        6500          1
           20 Marketing                            13000        6000          2
           60 IT                                    9000        4200          5
           80 Sales                                14000        6100         34

11 rows selected.
```

So what does `count(*)` mean? Count departments or what ?

Comment: It'll count the number of rows for each unique combination of the columns in your "group by"

Answer (score 0):

`count(*)` returns the rows that match the where statement.

In your case its `where e.department_id=d.department_id`.

Because you applied a group by your `count(*)` will return the count of rows for each group (`d.department_id`).

This means you will get  the count of employees (`e.department_id`) for each department (`d.department_id`).